# Receive values from array between other values

Tags: php, arrays

I have array, for example:

```
$array = (5, 2, 17, 9, 12, 6);
```

and always two values - `$first` and `$last`. I would like get all values from `$array` between `$first` and `$last`.

For example:

```
$first = 2;
$last = 6;
```

I would like receive:

```
$receive = array(17, 9, 12);
```

For example:

```
$first = 5;
$last = 9;
```

I would like receive:

```
$receive = array(2, 17);
```

How is the best way for that?

Comment: Take a look at [array_search()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) and [array_slice()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php) then

Comment: beats my `foreach()` idea :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search and slice:

```
$receive = array_slice($array,
                              $s=array_search($first, $array)+1,
                                 array_search($last, $array)-$s);
```